# using XML files in Windows Phone 7 and XNA 4.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I'm working on a basic tiling engine for XNA 4.0 on Windows Phone 7. I have a bunch of mapdata xml files with all the tile positions, powerup positions etc.

I was wondering what the best way of using these? I've read that if I want to use them with the Content then I have to alter the layout of the xml files.

Is there any way to load these files on to the device within the project and read the data from them?

Many thanks,
ant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I did it was make the XML file an embedded resource, not content, then I could access them in code:

```
Assembly app = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlType));
        string[] resources = app.GetManifestResourceNames();

        foreach (string resourceName in resources)
        {                                 
         xmlObject = (xmlType)ser.Deserialize(new StreamReader(app.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)));                    
        }
```

xmlType is a class that represents my XML Format

Comment: Cheers, will try this tonight, fingers crossed eh! I'm pretty new to C# so I don't understand the xmlType object you are using with the XmlSerializer but I'll have a search for this, the main problem was getting the xml on to the simulator, to use compile or not compile etc.

Comment: xmltype is a class generated when running xsd.exe against my XML. It is a class that represents my exact xml format. But serialization isnt the only or even best way to read xml. But, one of those resourceName strings will be your xml file then you should be able to use it in the manner you are familiar.